# Invalid Int "+" happens with any numerical operator

Tags: android, string, exception, numbers, operator-keyword

I am taking a crack at Android development and for my first app.. pun intended, I decided to go with a calculator. So my problem is that any arithmetic operator is evaluated as a numeric datatype and crashes the app. I've seen this discussed on other forums but most of them where syntactical issues, and I don't see that here. 
Anyway here is my code any help is appreciated.

```
public void btnEqual_Click(View v){
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
    String s = tv.getText().toString();
    Integer first;
    Integer second;
    Number result;
    Integer x;
    for(Integer i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1 ; i++){
        switch(s.charAt(i))
        {
            case '/': x = s.indexOf("/");
                first = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, x));
                second = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(x+1, s.length()));
                result =  first / second;
                tv2.setText(result.toString());
                break;
            case '*': x = s.indexOf("*");
                first = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, x));
                second = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(x+1, s.length()));
                result =  first * second;
                tv2.setText(result.toString());
                break;
            case '-': x = s.indexOf("-");
                first = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, x));
                second = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(x+1, s.length()));
                result =  first - second;
                tv2.setText(result.toString());
                break;
            case '+': x = s.indexOf("+");
                first = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, x));
                second = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(x+1, s.length()));
                result =  first + second;
                tv2.setText(result.toString());
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        if(!tv2.getText().toString().isEmpty()){break;}
    }
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "+"
```

Comment: Of course the above error message changes to match whatever operator I use when the void fires.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? What is being returned by `x = s.indexOf("+")`? It looks like `s.indexOf("+")` returns whichever operator you have entered and you are trying to assign that to your int variable `Integer x`.

Comment: `switch()` expects an integer, **not a character**. So, it correctly tells you that `'+'` is **not an integer**: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "+"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `x+1` in your substring, to cut the operator sign from the numerical value:

`Integer.valueOf(s.substring(x+1, s.length() - 1));`